# compile .hpp file in visual c++ CLR project

Tags: c++

Using VS2017, visual c++ -> CLR project trying to call unmanaged code.
Included test.hpp file in project and compiled [Failed]. test library is built in c++ builder5.0

test.hpp

```
#ifndef TESTHpp  
 #define TESTHpp

 extern "C" far char* _stdcall __declspec(dllimport) Get_Date();  

 #endif
```

Compiler error:

> "Error E0260 explicit type is missing ('int' assumed)"  --> at far
>   "Error E0065 expected a ';'"                            --> at far
>   "Error syntax error: 'char' should be preceded by ';'"   "Error C4430
>   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support
>   default-int"   "Error C2059 syntax error: '__declspec(dllimport)'"

getting this errors, far pointer is not recognising for that i included "minwindef.h", but can't edit existing test library's header file.
How to solve this without modifying existing .hpp? please give suggestions.

Comment: What is `far` supposed to be? Is that some compiler-specific extension?

Comment: `far` is a legacy macro that can be found in `minwindef.h`, if you can not edit `test.hpp` header then you need to include `minwindef.h` prior to it or manually define `far` prior to it.

Comment: Show the code where you include this file and minwindef.h.